# how to change font color of one column in grid

Tags: javascript

I've inherited javascript code (yii framework), which uses js.reconfigure, which displays data in a grid. The user has requested that the font for (only) one of the column headers be displayed in bold, red. How do I change that?

The line of code is:

```
{dataIndex: 'Test_Status', text: 'Testing Status', flex: 1, renderer: function (val, meta, record)  .. ..}
```

Comment: You can do it with CSS. What does the grid HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#t1 {
  /* uncomment this if you don't like the white lines between the cells */
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
}
#t1 td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td><td>Cell 6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 7</td><td>Cell 8</td><td>Cell 9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using developer tools in Chrome, I saw that the css renders to: <span id="gridcolumn-3117-textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Date Requested</span> , which I went ahead and found the css file, and added another class called "x-column-header-text-red", but where do I set this? It's not set in the js file.

Comment: @sharcfinz If the class "x-column-header-text" is already on every cell that you want to target, you can just use the CSS: `.x-column-header-text { background-color: red; }`. Otherwise, you'll need to add your new class, "x-column-header-text-red", to every element (td or span).

The neat thing about element classes is that you can have multiple (separated by a space). For instance: `<span id="gridcolumn-3117-textEl" class="x-column-header-text x-column-header-text-red">`

Comment: I only need to add it to 2 places, and can't seem to figure where to trigger it. I ended up figuring out that they used a sencha/ext.grid framework, and ended up putting the following inline - style: {color:'red'}, and that worked, but now I can't get it bolded. I've tried weight:'bold', font-weight:'bold', but nothing as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to add it inline:

```
style: {color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'},
```